# Usage of tribute after a longer period / alternative word/sentence

Tags: grammar, word-request, phrase-request, usage, sentence-request

Last year, a very popular actor, Irrfan Khan from India died. Tomorrow is his birthday (January 7). I wanted to make a pencil drawing to show my respect and love for him and his work in movies, and to show that he was the actor for whom everyone cared about and felt really sad when he died, last year. But I couldn't manage at that time. So I've made the drawing today and I'll post it tomorrow on his birthday. I've also written birth and death year using pencil on the drawing to convey he's no more.

But I can't compose a caption for posting it on social media/instagram etc.

Here are a few captions and problems/doubts related to them, that I've thought that I'll post along with photo of drawing:

1. Happy birthday to Irrfan (is *this* sentence used for only living persons)
2. a) A tribute to Irrfan Khan (Is tribute word relatable for the feelings I want to share)
   b)A tribute to Irrfan Khan (Is tribute a *too big* word compared to just a pencil drawing. Does tribute make sense only when you do something big, like shoot a short video for him, write a book on him etc.?)
   c) A tribute to Irrfan Khan (Is tribute word used tomorrow (Jan 7) as valid as it would be last year around his death date. Or it should be used only for recent deaths?)
3. Pencil drawing of late Irrfan Khan (is late word professional and okay to use to say he is no more?)
4. A tribute to late Irrfan Khan (If tribute is too big word, is there any similar appropriate sentence/phrase word for same?)
5. Remembering Irrfan Khan

So is any of them correct to use or can be improved?

Comment: A [**tribute**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tribute) *(an act, statement, or gift that is intended to show gratitude, respect, or admiration)* is fine. Your gesture does not need to be grand to qualify, and you don't need to mention 'late' in the title if your purpose becomes clear. A simple title like your "A tribute to Irrfan Khan" is better than one that tries too hard, or fumbles to find the right words.

Comment: "Purpose becomes clear" meaning? Can you please elaborate why we don't need "late"?

Comment: If the readers don't know who he was, they might not be interested anyway. Those who know, and appreciate your act, won't need to be told. If others are curious it can be inferred from the dates on your drawing anyway.

Comment: "Late" is fine to use, but it requires a definite article: "A tribute to **the** late Irrfan Khan."